# c# difference between two dates

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

in my GridView i have a method call `DisplayWarning()`

and I want to calculate the day difference between date column( in my SQL server ) and DateTime.Now and show one of my StatusIMG in `GridView` , This is `GridView`'s Code :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="InvoiceID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="InvoiceID" HeaderText="Rechnung Identifikation" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="InvoiceID" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerID" HeaderText="Kunde Identifikation" SortExpression="CustomerID" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Amount" HeaderText="Betrag" SortExpression="Amount" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Paid" HeaderText="Bezahlter Betrag" SortExpression="Paid" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Rest" HeaderText="Rest" SortExpression="Rest" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="PaymentType" HeaderText="Zahlungsart" SortExpression="PaymentType" />
    <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Shipped" HeaderText="erledigt" SortExpression="Shipped" />
    <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# DisplayWarning() %>' Width="16" />     
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

</Columns>
```

And this is `DisplayWarning()` method :

```
public string DisplayWarning()
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RechnungConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand datecmd = new SqlCommand("Select DATEDIFF(day,Date,Getdate()) as DiffDate From Invoice", conn);
    SqlDataReader Reader = datecmd.ExecuteReader();
    int RegTime;
    Reader.Read();
    RegTime = Convert.ToInt32(Reader["DiffDate"]); 
    string StatusColor;
    if (RegTime < 7)
    {
        StatusColor = "Image/green-4040.jpg";
    }
    else if (RegTime >= 7 && RegTime < 14)
    {
        StatusColor = "Image/yellow-4040.jpg";
    }
    else if (RegTime >= 14 && RegTime < 21)
    {
        StatusColor = "Image/orange-4040.jpg";
    }
    else
    {
        StatusColor = "Image/red-4040.jpg";
    }
    conn.Close();
    return StatusColor;

}
```

But the problem is when this code runs , only calculate time difference 1's row in the database and for other rows put same `RegTime` and it fails

Comment: Your code doesn't do any looping. It is only ever going to look at the first row, which by the way can be different each time you run this because you have no order by on your query.

Comment: In my opinion there are two ways. Or you will call that method on each dataitem bound and calculate the datediff with Id which will be added to sqlcommand, so it will calculate diff per record. Or you should make a loop that will perform datediff for everyrecord with Reader.Next() until end of records.

Comment: My suggestion is to add datediff computation to main sql you using for binding grid and then in RowDataBound set appropriate color depending on datediff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general it would be better to load these values into the DataSource of the GridView. Then you don't have to acess the database again for every row.

However, according to the problem with the `DataReader`, you have to use a (while)-loop to loop all rows in a `DataReader` like here:

```
public string DisplayWarning()
{
    using(var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RechnungConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    using (var datecmd = new SqlCommand("Select DATEDIFF(day,Date,Getdate()) as DiffDate From Invoice", conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (var reader = datecmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.HasRows){
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    int regTime = reader.GetInt32(0);
                    string statusColor;
                    if (regTime < 7)
                    {
                        statusColor = "Image/green-4040.jpg";
                    }
                    else if (regTime >= 7 && regTime < 14)
                    {
                        statusColor = "Image/yellow-4040.jpg";
                    }
                    else if (regTime >= 14 && regTime < 21)
                    {
                        StatusColor = "Image/orange-4040.jpg";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        statusColor = "Image/red-4040.jpg";
                    }
                    returnstatusColor;
                }
            }
            else{ 
                // output, log, exception ?!
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I've also changed some other things like using `using`-statements which is always a good idea to ensure that f.e. a connection gets closed (even on error).

**Update**: but you want to call this method for every row, then you need to pass the key of the row to this, so that you can pass that as parameter to the sql-query:

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# DisplayWarning(System.Convert.ToInt32(Eval("InvoiceID"))) %>' Width="16" />
```

Codebehind (presuming that the key is an `int`):

```
public string DisplayWarning(int invoiceID)
{
    string sql = @"Select DATEDIFF(day,Date,Getdate()) as DiffDate 
                   From Invoice 
                   WHERE InvoiceID=@InvoiceID";
    using(var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RechnungConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    using (var datecmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
    {
        datecmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@InvoiceID", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = invoiceID;
        // Here you don't need a loop since you only get one row back
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: thank u Tim, `DisplayWarning()` need some string return , but in While loop how can i return StatusColor for all rows !?

Comment: @MaziarMalekian: `DisplayWarning` is called from aspx for every row anyway. So with your approach you cannot do it in one go. You have to modify the main sql-query which loads the datasource for the grid which i don't know. Then you could join the `Invoice` table to the datasource-table and calculate the DateDiff value as additional column. Then you can `Bind` or `Eval` this column  to the image's `ImageUrl` property.

Comment: @MaziarMalekian Assuming you just update `DisplayWarning()`, rather than datasource, then DisplayWarning() will need to accept the key for each row as an argument, and include that key as part of the sql query, so it knows what row to check and what status to return.

Comment: @MaziarMalekian: i have overlooked that you have to pass the row-key as parameter to your method anyway. I've edited my answer to take that into account. (Thanks Joel Coehoorn)

Comment: @TimSchmelter woooooww :> it's worked ! i dont know how to thank u i am soo happy :>, and JoelCoehoom thank you too man ! <3 you :D

Answer (score 0):

Update `SqlDataSource1` to include this calculation as part of the result set. More than that, also use an sql `CASE` statement to return the whole image string. Then you can bind that directly to the image control.

Comment: thank u Joel, i am newbee :( can u show me how can i update `SqlDataSource1` for this calculation ?!

Comment: @MaziarMalekian I'd need to see how it's defined.

Answer (score 0):

what about add this property in your datasource? Would be more clean solution.